# Apple push notifications certificate on windows server

Tags: ios, ssl, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to generate a new push notifications certificate on my IIS.
In the past I used to go to IIS mamager --> Server Certificates then select "Create Certificate Request", fill out the details and it generated a txt file which I uploaded to apple to generate and download the cer file.

My problem is that for some reason I can't upload this text file. I get this message:

Invalid CSR

Select a valid Certificate Signing Request

anyone encountered this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got it working.
This is what I did:

In IIS using Cygwin:

1. Generate private key:

   ```
   openssl genrsa -out myAppName.key 2048
   ```
2. Generate csr file from private key:

   ```
   openssl req -new -sha256 -key myAppNameCSR.key -out myAppName.csr
   ```
3. Upload csr file to apple to generate certificate
4. Download the certificate
5. Convert certificate to pem file

   ```
   openssl x509 -in aps_development.cer -inform der -out myAppNameCert.pem
   ```
6. Generate pfx file

   ```
   openssl pkcs12 -export -out myAppNameKey.pfx -inkey myAppNameCSR.key -in myAppNameCert.pem
   ```

To install the certificate in Windows Server:

Click Start > Run.
At the prompt, type in mmc, and then click OK to open the Microsoft Management Console.

Click File, and then click Add/Remove Snap-in.
Click Certificates from the list of available snap-ins, and then click Add..

Click Computer account.

Click Next, and then click Finish.
Click OK.
Right-click the Personal tree node and select All Tasks >Import.

Follow the Wizard, pointing it to the pfx file generated and provide the password used to secure it during creation.
Under the Personal tree node, double-click the Certificates folder.
Right-click the newly installed certificate.
Select All Tasks > Manage Private Keys.

In the Security tab, add the Network Service account providing Read access.
add the group IIS_IUSRS to the private key, and make sure it has full control.

Making a PEM File with Cygwin

So now you have these files:
The private key as a pfx file 
The SSL certificate, aps_development.cer as pem file

Convert the pfx file to pem file:

```
openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out myAppNameKey.pem -in myAppNameKey.pfx
```

Finally, combine the certificate and key into a single .pem file:

```
cat myAppNameCert.pem myAppNameKey.pem > ckDevelopment.pem
```

Hope this saves someone some time...

Answer (score 0):

use Your keychain Access to genarate Certificate Signing Request

this tutorial might help you - 
http://quickblox.com/developers/How_to_create_APNS_certificates

Comment: my problem is generating the cer on a windows server and the tutorial is for mac. On mac there is no problem because I can generate the csr file using the keychain access